# How do I fix this error? E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_deb_opera_com_opera-stable_stable-jammy.list

Tags: package-management, updates, dpkg, 22.04

I've tried a bunch of things I've come across here, tried adding to repository, tried rebuilding source list, tried just removing but nothing works I just keep getting the same code over and over.

Comment: What is the problem with removing the file?

Comment: I literally can't do anything, if I try to remove with sudo apt rm or remove it pops same error. I can't update or install anything

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of the following command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_deb_opera_com_opera-stable_stable-jammy.list`

Comment: FYI, if you use the linked answer, you should know that the file you're using isn't your main `/etc/apt/sources.list` file so you'd have to apply the answer to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_deb_opera_com_opera-stable_stable-jammy.list` file and most of those answers don't really apply. Until we know the contents of your file, we won't know what the problem is.

Comment: Please run `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_deb_opera_com_opera-stable_stable-jammy.list` to remove the file.

Comment: That fixed it thank you very much